# Abaqus composite ply strain extraction

Tags: matlab, finite-element-analysis, abaqus

I'm trying to extract ply strains from a composite shell model in Abaqus. I would like to be able to export (to a .dat (preferably) or any sort of text file) every ply strain in every element.

So far I have managed to find a method to extract the ply with the max strain in each element to the .rpt file, but I would like to export all plies of every element to the .dat.

I'm doing this as a part of parametric study and need to post process later in Matlab. Any knowledge on the keywords/options to include in the .inp file would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt whether you can directly export to a mat-file, however you should be able to either a) [read the rpt file in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46995-read-the-contents-of-an-abaqus-rpt-file) or b) export plain text files using the Abaqus python API and import those in MATLAB.

Comment: I don't need to export directly to a .mat file, just to any .txt file alternative, i.e. .dat as Abaqus does. The problem with the .rpt file is that it doesn't show all the plies of every element, only the envelope (max) value. Which isn't very useful for looking at the strains through the thickness of the laminate.

Comment: I have previously used the Abaqus python API to extract stresses and strains from an odb file. However, there is no general way of doing it since it depends on your specific setup (part names, element types, ...). An introductory tutorial can be found at http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~mcarrara3/dataExtraction_v1.pdf. If you need specific advise, please either rephrase your question or ask a new one.

Comment: I have used python to extract stresses and displacements before but was hoping to avoid using python as my post processing is already in matlab. It might be that I need to go back to python. It just seems strange that I can't get the *el print keyword to print every ply strain to the .dat file.